# call a web service from a button click

Tags: java, netbeans, web, service, jframe

I have a jFrame, it has a label, textfield and a submit button.
I have a webservice that prints out "Welcome to JAX-WS web services with SOAP, + name taken from textfield"

How do I call a web service from a button click?

Comment: Swallow one thing at a time: If you're new to both concepts, learn to do them in isolation of each other before trying to combine them since the combined complexities are more than additive. I don't do web services, and so can't give specific recommendations regarding them, but if this were my project, I'd perhaps [start with Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LEND_enUS445US445&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=web%20services%20swing%20java).

Comment: All I'm asking is how do I call a web service on a button click. My web service generated sources and i'm trying to access a file called WelcomeSOAP.java

Answer (score 0):

Hi
The below is the pseudo code
 Generate Stubs to your SOAP service then acquire service object like below

```
Proxy proxy = .. //get proxy object
Service service = proxy.getService(); // get service object...
```

On the button click handler execute your web service operation/method like below,let's suppose return type of your service is Helloworld

```
Helloworld helloWorld = service.getHelloworld();
```

Now you are having the return object, do according to your requirement like printing `"Welcome to ...."+ helloWorld.getName()` which you have entered in text field
Once again the below is just Pseudo code
Thaks

Comment: Hi,
I don't know what "Proxy" does.
Do you know of a different solution?

Comment: @John If you know SOAP web service by this time you would know that what is a proxy? which is an entry point to access your service .Main aim is getting the service object check your generated source code what are the different ways to get the service object.Using that object execute your business logic